# jquery ajax call only triggering once in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, jquery-mobile

not sure if that is a new problem or not but so far I didn´t find any solution for it. I have the following function in my system - a jquery mobile MVC web application - and it works great in all browsers except IE (9 in my case). It works always the first time I call it but the second time it always fails and I have no idea why.

Thanks very much for your help in advance!

```
    function getAndShowPflichten(immoid, days) {

            var seite = 1;

            if (sessionStorage.getItem("seite") != null) {
                seite = sessionStorage.getItem("seite");
            }

            if (immoid == "") {
                alert("No ID found!");
                return;
            } else {
                $.post("getPflichtenFuerImmobilieJson", { id: immoid, frist: days, seite: seite }, showInspections, 'json').fail(
                function () { alert("Überprüfen Sie bitte Ihre Datenverbindung."); $.mobile.loading('hide'); });
            }
        }
```

The method in the MVC Controller is:

```
public ActionResult getPflichtenFuerImmobilieJson(int id, int frist, int seite)
        {
            if (loggedIn())
            {
                int benutzerLoggedIn = Convert.ToInt32(Session["benutzerId"]);
                var model = immoVerwalter.getPflichtenFuerImmobilieJson(benutzerLoggedIn, id, frist, seite);

                return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("abgemeldet", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to say I am using jquery 1.7.1 and jquery-mobile 1.2.0

Comment: any errors in the browser console

Comment: sadly not, but if I switch to Compatibility View then it works every time ...

Comment: can you check whether the method getAndShowPflichten() is getting called every time

Comment: no it´s not, seems he doesn´t find the correct Method in my Controller anymore ... strange

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with the way the IE and other browsers handle the jquery mobile urls in Chrome it is "http://localhost:2002/Mobile/Home/Login" and in IE "http://localhost:2002/Mobile/#/Mobile/Home/Login" ...

Comment: hmmmm or not cause with Compatibility View on it is the same  "localhost:2002/Mobile/#/Mobile/Home/Login" and there it works

Comment: can you also share how the method is called

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it has nothing to do with Ajax or other things, seems that the method for the variable days (see below) is not called - days is null the second time it is called ...

```
var days = $("#interval").val();
```